# Can't do Local fowarding from a local host to a remote host

Tags: networking, server, permissions, ssh

On Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS I have tried to configure a basic Linux server with monit. I'm doing this on my own computer to learn to be a sysadmin. I am connected to port 2812 locally and the syntax I've put in my monitrc file is ok when I test the output.

`jordan@jordan-All-Series:/$ sudo monit -t
[sudo] password for jordan: 
Control file syntax OK
jordan@jordan-All-Series:/$ sudo monit
Starting Monit 5.25.1 daemon with http interface at [localhost]:2812
jordan@jordan-All-Series:/$ sudo monit status`

However when I try to forward the server port to the local port:

`ssh -L 8383:localhost:2812 root@My_Local_Ip_Address`

It now asks for a password that isn't there and then after the thrid and final retry it wants a public key or password. I use the same password to access Ubuntu as I do for the montric file. I looked at a few forums and ended up generating a rsa key pair with the ssh-keygen command. Nothing has changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you log in as jordan you are supplying the password for the jordan account. The same applies when you execute the sudo command: you are asked for the password for the jordan account.

In your ssh command you are connecting as the root user which will have a different password. By default in Ubuntu this is unset.

Try `jordan@` instead of `root@` in your ssh command.